# Accessing nested class constructor

Tags: c++, nested-class

How can I write code for a nested class' constructor? Because the following example gives me errors

**foo.h**

```
class foo
{
    public:
       class bar
        {
           public:
           bar();
           ~bar();
        }
    private:

}
```

**foo.cpp**

```
#include "foo.h"

foo::bar()
{

}
```

Comment: Please give the errors and the sections of code causing them when you ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to explicitly name the constructor as a member of `foo::bar`, not of `foo`. Adjust the name like this:

```
foo::bar::bar() {}
//      ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Since bar is a "derived class" of foo, which means if you want to access function bar(), you need to access the class bar first.

bar() is in the namespace of foo::bar::

You need to try foo::bar::bar()

Answer (score 0):

```
class foo {
public:
    foo() : _bar(this) {}

    class bar {
    public:
        bar(const foo* base);
        ~bar() {}
    private:
        const foo* _base;
    };
private:
    bar _bar;
};

foo::bar::bar(const foo* base) : _base(base) {}
```

add in a variable in there to also show how you can call the outer class functions inside the nested class if need as well.

As a side not you also have error with your syntax.  You are missing a ; on the classes closing }.